# Modal view that does not prevent access to parent

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a two ViewController solution where a modal view controller is presented over a UICollectionView while allowing the user to interact with the CollectionView.  In this case, it is like an advanced picker, allowing the user to choose items that will populate the properties in the modal view before saving a record.

I have a presentation controller setup to present the view how and where I want, allowing full visibility to the parent view.  Nothing I have tried will allow the user to interact with (scroll, tap, etc) the UIController view.

[image]

In view debugging, I see a UITransitionView that has a frame equal to the full screen. (see image)  I suspect that this is the culprit.  Is this even possible in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a modal view controller is that it takes over the screen and demands that the user respond to it before doing anything else. It puts your program into a "mode" that must be dismissed before the user can go on. That is the core reason for being of a modal dialog.

If you can interact with the view controller underneath the the top view controller is no longer a modal.

What you are trying to do is wrong from a human interface standpoint, and not supported by the application framework. You need to rethink your design.

### Edit:

Top-level view controllers are not designed to share the screen. If you want another view controller to cover part of the screen while the user can still interact with the view controller underneath then you should use a container view as @МаксудДаудов suggests in his answer.

I would probably put a container view on top of the rest of my view controller's content, control-drag an embed segue to the child view controller I want to display, add an outlet to the container view, and then hide the container view.

When you want to display the "picker", you could then un-hide the container view, which would reveal the child view inside and let the user interact with it, while still being able to interact with the other components in your main view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

I don't see this as too different from what apple does with the iOS Mail app currently.  It allows a user to slide a new message VC down to access other mail content.  This design only adds a delegate that sends a selected record to the presented view.  Perhaps modal views and presentation controllers is the wrong approach, but I will disagree that this is wrong from a human interface standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way allowing presented full screen view controller to interact view controller under that. Instead , add your second view controller at containercontroller at some part of first, and change first VCs collection view frame accordingly, to be able see all the list. Doing this, you will have two view controllers working together

Comment: Thanks.  So in this case, the second VC would be a child of the UICollectionVC?

Comment: @BBruce, yes, it’s child view controller.